# Centering color key at bottom of heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

I tried to generate a heatmap using `heatmap.2` in `gplots` package. My aim is to generate a heatmap with no extra space between plot area and heatmap (excluding the key at the bottom). By looking at some posts, I managed to fit heatmap to plot area using `lmat` (so that there are no space at left part). But **I cannot center the color key below the plot**. As a result, **there is some space because of the projected a color scale scale at the right side**. 
Can anyone tell me how to make the color key at the center of the heatmap at bottom part (thus to avoid extra space problem). 
I am unable to show the image. I use following code to generate heatmap.

```
library(gplots)
dat <- read.csv("C:..../xxx.csv")
dat_matrix <- data.matrix(dat)
colors = c(seq(-2,-1,length=100),seq(-1,1,length=100),seq(1,2,length=100))
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("green","black","red"))(n = 299)
lmat = rbind(c(1,3),c(2,1),c(1,4))
lwid = c(1,4)
lhei = c(1,4,1.2)
heatmap.2(dat_matrix, dendrogram="none", Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE,
          col = my_palette, breaks = colors, scale = "none", key = TRUE,
          density.info = "none", trace = "none", labRow = FALSE, symm = FALSE,
          symkey = TRUE, symbreaks = TRUE, lmat = lmat, lwid = lwid, lhei = lhei)
```

Comment: Please make it easier for people to help you by providing a [**self contained example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). E.g., use data from the first example in `?heatmap.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the parameter `key.par` and set the `mar` to something suitable. For example using `dat_matrix  <- as.matrix(mtcars)` and otherwise your data, I used `mar=c(8,0,0,12)`. You'll have to figure out what `mar` best fits your data.

```
heatmap.2(dat_matrix, 
          dendrogram="none", 
          Rowv=FALSE, 
          Colv=FALSE, 
          col = my_palette, 
          breaks=colors,      
          scale="none", 
          key=TRUE, 
          key.par = list(mar= c(8, 0, 0, 12)),
          density.info="none", 
          trace="none", 
          labRow=FALSE, 
          symm=F,
          symkey=T,
          symbreaks=T, 
          lmat = lmat, 
          lwid = lwid, 
          lhei = lhei)
```